More complete English reference to the Harari language than what is linked on Wikipedia?
The Wikipedia article on Harari language links to an Appendix 2 of the works of one 'Burton' (absent from the article itself, apparently that would be Richard Francis Burton, and the book 'First footsteps in East Africa
or, An Exploration of Harar').
Unfortunately that appendix is very incomplete, and partially quite unclear.
(Several sentences seem to reference other parts that do not actually exist? Most poignantly, the reference appears insufficient to reenact the sample translations contained therein.)
The website of the city of Harar apparently contains current learning resources, but as far as I can see, those are all themselves written in Harari, thence requiring an entry level that the Appendix, I feel, cannot bootstrap.
Are more comprehensive English learning resources available?
(This is for a hobby project with the goal limited to being able to construct simple sentences/expressions with dictionary assistance and, ideally, getting a feel for what would/not sound ideomatic. "Live" utilisation in Harar or even fluency are very much out of scope.)

English learning resources??

Resources whose language is English, but for learning Harari, I guess.

@Lambie : Like the linked 'Appendix 2'. Or like, say, the kind of school book children are handed for learning their first or second foreign language. Like The Klingon Dictionary. I also found a reference, similar to this 'Appendix 2' but way more (and sufficiently) comprehensive for Doric Greek (but it's currently down).

Klingon, really? That's not a real language, it's made up.

Doric Greek and Klingon? Klingon is a made-up or constructed language.

Maybe you can contact these people: https://elalliance.com/harari/ It only has 25,000 native speakers...And it is not a written language, either: https://www.wollamshram.ca/1001/East/east1_appn02.htm

Err, according to Wikipedia it is written in no less than three alphabets?

But the idea is sound to write to this 'ELAT' and I have done so. Will report back about their response.

The comment thread mentioning Klingon almost tripped me up thinking Harari is a constructed language, since we also have a sister site for that, [conlang.se].

FWIW: I have yet to hear back from ELAT. I guess I'll also try the maintainer of the 'City of Harar' website, though they probably have very little use for resources in yet another, foreign language, considering they already deal with a multi-lingual homeland.
